# Creating a template using ext component

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to have a template using tpl with their existing data but I also want to add in ext component inside too! Secondly, I cannot view the Book..I'm not sure why

```
var Book = Ext.create('Ext.view.View', {
        width: 300,
        height: 150,
        store: books,
        title: 'Books',
        tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                '<tpl for=".">',
                    '<div style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="thumb-wrap">',
                      '<br/><span>**EXT component here**</span>',
                      '<br/><span>{booktitle}</span>',
                    '</div>',
                '</tpl>'
        ),
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
```

Any advice on what should I do/not do?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
var Book = Ext.create('Ext.dataview.DataView', {
        width: 300,
        height: 150,
        store: books,
        title: 'Books',
        itemTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                '<tpl for=".">',
                    '<div style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="thumb-wrap">',
                      '<br/><span>**EXT component here**</span>',
                      '<br/><span>{booktitle}</span>',
                    '</div>',
                '</tpl>'
        ),
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
```

Using components can't be done. Not that I know.